# Audio file class

Tags: vb.net, events, audio

I am using VB.net VS2012 and would like some help playing an Audio file.

Here is my code:

```
''' <summary>
''' This class is a wrapper for the Windows API calls to play wave, midi or mp3 files.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' </remarks>
Public Class AudioFile
'***********************************************************************************************************
'        Class:  PlayFile
'   Written By:  Blake Pell (bpell@indiana.edu)
' Initial Date:  03/31/2007
' Last Updated:  02/04/2009
'***********************************************************************************************************

' Windows API Declarations
Private Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Int32, ByVal hwndCallback As Int32) As Int32

''' <summary>
''' Constructor:  Location is the filename of the media to play.  Wave files and Mp3 files are the supported formats.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Location"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub New(ByVal location As String)
    Me.Filename = location
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Plays the file that is specified as the filename.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub Play()

    If _filename = "" Or Filename.Length <= 4 Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Right(Filename, 3).ToLower
        Case "mp3"
            mciSendString("open """ & _filename & """ type mpegvideo alias audiofile", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)

            Dim playCommand As String = "play audiofile from 0"

            If _wait = True Then playCommand += " wait"

            mciSendString(playCommand, Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        Case "wav"
            mciSendString("open """ & _filename & """ type waveaudio alias audiofile", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
            mciSendString("play audiofile from 0", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        Case "mid", "idi"
            mciSendString("stop midi", "", 0, 0)
            mciSendString("close midi", "", 0, 0)
            mciSendString("open sequencer!" & _filename & " alias midi", "", 0, 0)
            mciSendString("play midi", "", 0, 0)
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("File type not supported.")
            Call Close()
    End Select

    IsPaused = False

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Pause the current play back.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub Pause()
    mciSendString("pause audiofile", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    IsPaused = True
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Resume the current play back if it is currently paused.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub [Resume]()
    mciSendString("resume audiofile", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    IsPaused = False
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Stop the current file if it's playing.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub [Stop]()
    mciSendString("stop audiofile", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Close the file.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub Close()
    mciSendString("close audiofile", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub

Private _wait As Boolean = False
''' <summary>
''' Halt the program until the .wav file is done playing.  Be careful, this will lock the entire program up until the
''' file is done playing.  It behaves as if the Windows Sleep API is called while the file is playing (and maybe it is, I don't
''' actually know, I'm just theorizing).  :P
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property Wait() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _wait
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _wait = value
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Sets the audio file's time format via the mciSendString API.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
ReadOnly Property Milleseconds() As Integer
    Get
        Dim buf As String = Space(255)
        mciSendString("set audiofile time format milliseconds", Nothing, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        mciSendString("status audiofile length", buf, 255, IntPtr.Zero)

        buf = Replace(buf, Chr(0), "") ' Get rid of the nulls, they muck things up

        If buf = "" Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return CInt(buf)
        End If
    End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Gets the status of the current playback file via the mciSendString API.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
ReadOnly Property Status() As String
    Get
        Dim buf As String = Space(255)
        mciSendString("status audiofile mode", buf, 255, IntPtr.Zero)
        buf = Replace(buf, Chr(0), "")  ' Get rid of the nulls, they muck things up
        Return buf
    End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Gets the file size of the current audio file.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
ReadOnly Property FileSize() As Integer
    Get
        Try
            Return My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(_filename).Length
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return 0
        End Try
    End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Gets the channels of the file via the mciSendString API.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
ReadOnly Property Channels() As Integer
    Get
        Dim buf As String = Space(255)
        mciSendString("status audiofile channels", buf, 255, IntPtr.Zero)

        If IsNumeric(buf) = True Then
            Return CInt(buf)
        Else
            Return -1
        End If
    End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Used for debugging purposes.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
ReadOnly Property Debug() As String
    Get
        Dim buf As String = Space(255)
        mciSendString("status audiofile channels", buf, 255, IntPtr.Zero)

        Return Str(buf)
    End Get
End Property

Private _isPaused As Boolean = False
''' <summary>
''' Whether or not the current playback is paused.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property IsPaused() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isPaused
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _isPaused = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _filename As String
''' <summary>
''' The current filename of the file that is to be played back.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property Filename() As String
    Get
        Return _filename
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(value) = False Then
            Throw New System.IO.FileNotFoundException
            Exit Property
        End If

        _filename = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

This code works well. Can I please have some help to create an Event that will be called when the Audio file has finished playing. When an Audio file has finished, the 'Status' is 'Stopped'. How can I check to see when this happens and create an Event for it?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to a way to register a callback for when the playback status changes, so you'll have to use an observer (i.e. a timer).

```
Private WithEvents StatusMonitor As New Timers.Timer(100)
Private Property LastStatus As String

Private Sub StatusMonitor_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles StatusMonitor.Elapsed
    If Not String.Equals(Me.Status, Me.LastStatus) Then
        Me.LastStatus = Me.Status
        RaiseEvent PlaybackStatusChanged(Me, New PlaybackStatusChangedEventArgs(Me.Status))
    End If
End Sub

Public Event PlaybackStatusChanged(sender As Object, e As PlaybackStatusChangedEventArgs)

Public Class PlaybackStatusChangedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Private _status As String

    Public Sub New(status As String)
        _status = status
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Status As String
        Get
            Return _status
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

What this does is it stores the status in a private property and compares it to the current status every 100ms. If the status has changed, it fires the `PlaybackStatusChanged` event, along with arguments containing the new status. You can then listen for this event, and check `e.Status` in the event callback as if you were directly getting it from `AudioFile.Status`.

**EDIT**

After doing a couple of test runs, I've found that the status property behaves inconsistently. It seems to return a lot of whitespace as well, for reasons that I can't seem to figure out. Anyway, as a result, the status passed to the status event is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do that. But what you could do is this. On your main form, Dim a string like lol as string

Now for a button, set this code:

```
lol = "Audio file path goes here :3"
    Dim audio As New AudioFile(lol)
    Timer1.Start()
    audio.Play()
```

Add a timer, and set its interval to 10.

For the timer code add this:

```
 Dim audio As New AudioFile(lol)
    If audio.Status.Contains("stopped") Then
        audio.Play()
    End If
```

That way, when the song is done playing, the timer will automatically start playing it again. And its set for the audio file that's on that variable, so just have the button set the path on that variable and boom. Your set.

Hope that helped...